# Use classes that implements "Listeners" in enum

Tags: java, events, enums, listener

Anyone knows how to use a class as a parameter that need to implement "Listener" in enums?

For example, I want to load some classes dynamically via EventType.MY_LISTENER.register();

```
public enum EventType {
    GAME_START(GameStartListener.class);

    private Class<?> clazz;

    EventType(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void register() {
        Main.registerListener(this.clazz);
    }
}
```

"GameStartListener" is a class which implements "Listener", but I'm not really sure how to do this, because it shows me an syntax error at:

```
Main.registerListener(this.clazz);
```

"java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class cannot be converted to my.package.Listener"

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Main.registerListener` expects `Listener` type and you're passing actually `Class<GameStartListener>` (a type holding meta-data about your `GameStartListener` class) instead real `GameStartListener` object.